# laravel 5.1 Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I do install an laravel 5.1 aplication on a webserver.

I see this error: Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /home/mydomain/public_html/myapp/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 646

I try to set file permissions to 775 or 777 but did not work.

How can i fix this error?

Comment: pretty sure the error is coming from your controller/view look at line 646 on both to see if you are using a function incorrectly as the error states.

Comment: can you post your code ??

Comment: i will check the code in about 4 hours from now. I can see the code right now . Thought was a permission problem

Comment: I received this error once, and in my case it was due to `php` version not supported by Laravel, if you forgot to check that.